# C# Indexer Usage

Tags: c#, properties, indexer

To have an indexer we use the following format:

```
class ClassName
{
    DataType[] ArrayName = new DataType[Length]; 

    public DataType this[int i]
    {
        get { return ArrayName[i]; }
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I used the format, even though we can go for a custom indexer also. According to my understanding, we are keeping a propery array that is indexed.

My question is :

1. Is it a templated property?
2. When and where could we achieve high degree code optimization using this indexer?

Comment: this supremely dominating question has a meteorically hyperbolic title.

Comment: It was a perfectly cromulent title.

Comment: Geez lighten up.  People are here to ask questions and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about code optimization.
You could write a method in your class that can get you the item from the collection it holds.

e.g.

```
public DataType GetItemByIndex(int i)
{
}
```

Indexers are in a way, "syntactic sugar", to let users treat the instance as an array or collection.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a *templated* property, it is a *parameterful* property - that is a property that accepts a parameter argument.

This boils down to simply a `get_Item(Int32)` method in place of a `get_Item()` method that would normally be emitted by the compiler in place of a parameterless property.  As such this doesn't open up much opportunities for optimization.