# Can someone explain this C# syntax?

Tags: c#

What's actually going on here:

```
public decimal[] Coefficients;
public decimal this[int i]
{
    get { return Coefficients[i]; }
    set { Coefficients[i] = value; }
}
```

What does the `this` serve as? Is it some sort of extension to the `decimal`?

Comment: If your class is called MathTest, then it allows you to access the internal Coefficients array by using MathTest[i] instead of MathTest.Coefficients[i]. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307354/c-sharp-indexer-usage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185071/real-world-use-cases-for-c-sharp-indexers

Comment: Why the downvotes ..

Comment: No idea. I upvoted you. Question seems clear enough to me. Perhaps rather poorly researched, as it's a basic lanuage syntax question, but still valid IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

Example from the linked MSDN:

```
class SampleCollection<T>
{
    // Declare an array to store the data elements.
    private T[] arr = new T[100];

    // Define the indexer, which will allow client code
    // to use [] notation on the class instance itself.
    // (See line 2 of code in Main below.)        
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets
            // the corresponding element from the internal array.
            return arr[i];
        }
        set
        {
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    }
}

// This class shows how client code uses the indexer.
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare an instance of the SampleCollection type.
        SampleCollection<string> stringCollection = new SampleCollection<string>();

        // Use [] notation on the type.
        stringCollection[0] = "Hello, World";
        System.Console.WriteLine(stringCollection[0]);
    }
}
// Output:
// Hello, World.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an indexer it will be called when you use syntax like obj[1]. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever wondered how `List<T>`'s `myList[i]` works in c# just like an array ?

The Answer is in your question. The syntax you posted is a syntactic sugar that the compiler transforms into properties called `get_Item(int index)` and `set_Item(int index, decimal value)`. It is used in `List<T>` for example to access the internal array used in the class and return the element at the specified index (set or get). This feature is called an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

To test that yourself, try to create a method with same signature :

```
public decimal get_Item(int i)
{
     return 0;
}
```

You'll get a compiler error :

> Error CS0082: Type 'MyClass' already reserves a member called
>   'get_Item' with the same parameter types